# Compiling boost with mingw-w64

Tags: c++, boost, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I need to compile boost on my windows 64bit machine with mingw-w64. I tried linking to precompiled boost_filesystem-vc100-mt and boost_system-vc100-mt from http://boost.teeks99.com/, boost_1_46_1-vc64-bin.exe. But it just gives tons of errors about linking

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o dist/MiMBL_GeneDel.exe MiMBL_GeneDel.o -Llibs  -L/cygdrive/c/Lindoapi/bin/win64 -L/cygdrive/c/
Lindoapi/lib/win64 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK -lglpk -lboost_filesystem-vc100-mt -lboost_syste
m-vc100-mt -llindo64_6_1 -lmosek64_6_0 -lconopt3 -lpthread -lm
Warning: .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib" /DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib" /DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecogni
zed
Warning: .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib" /DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib" /DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecogni
zed
Warning: .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized
Warning: .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib" /DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib" /DEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecogni
zed
MiMBL_GeneDel.o:/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/filesystem/v3/path.hpp:288: undefined reference to
`boost::filesystem3::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>
, std::allocator<char> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, int> const&)'
MiMBL_GeneDel.o:/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/filesystem/v3/path.hpp:377: undefined reference to
`boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet()'
MiMBL_GeneDel.o:/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp:218: undefined referen
ce to `boost::filesystem3::detail::status(boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
MiMBL_GeneDel.o:/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/boost/filesystem/v3/path_traits.hpp:174: undefined refere
nce to `boost::filesystem3::path_traits::convert(char const*, char const*, std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<w
char_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, int> const&)'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi06.obj):(.text[preprocess_and_solve_lp]+0x317): undefined reference to `__security_check_cook
ie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi06.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$preprocess_and_solve_lp]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCh
eck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi06.obj):(.text[glp_simplex]+0x4b9): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi06.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_simplex]+0x20): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi01.obj):(.text[glp_copy_prob]+0x388): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_copy_prob]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi12.obj):(.text[copy_bfcp]+0x45): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi12.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$copy_bfcp]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi12.obj):(.text[glp_set_bfcp]+0x2f0): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi12.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_set_bfcp]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi12.obj):(.text[glp_factorize]+0x14b): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi12.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_factorize]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpenv06.obj):(.text[glp_time]+0x128): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpenv06.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_time]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi09.obj):(.text[preprocess_and_solve_mip]+0x196): undefined reference to `__security_check_coo
kie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi09.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$preprocess_and_solve_mip]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerC
heck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi09.obj):(.text[glp_intopt]+0x857): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi09.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_intopt]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplpx01.obj):(.text[_glp_lpx_set_int_parm]+0x48e): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie
'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplpx01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_lpx_set_int_parm]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChec
k'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplpx01.obj):(.text[_glp_lpx_get_int_parm]+0x1a3): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie
'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplpx01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_lpx_get_int_parm]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChec
k'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplpx01.obj):(.text[_glp_lpx_simplex]+0xb6): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplpx01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_lpx_simplex]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplpx01.obj):(.text[_glp_lpx_exact]+0x93): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplpx01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_lpx_exact]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplpx01.obj):(.text[solve_mip]+0x360): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplpx01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$solve_mip]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplib02.obj):(.text[_glp_lib_xlmul]+0xad): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplib02.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_lib_xlmul]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplib02.obj):(.text[_glp_lib_xldiv]+0x208): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glplib02.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_lib_xldiv]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpenv08.obj):(.text[_glp_xdlopen]+0x53): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpenv08.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_xdlopen]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios01.obj):(.text[_glp_ios_solve_node]+0x154): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_ios_solve_node]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'

libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios03.obj):(.text[show_progress]+0x234): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$show_progress]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios03.obj):(.text[branch_on]+0x771): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$branch_on]+0x38): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi08.obj):(.text[glp_interior]+0x35c): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi08.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_interior]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmps.obj):(.text[read_columns]+0x53d): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmps.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$read_columns]+0x2c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmps.obj):(.text[read_rhs]+0x2e4): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmps.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$read_rhs]+0x24): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmps.obj):(.text[read_ranges]+0x391): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmps.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$read_ranges]+0x24): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmps.obj):(.text[read_bounds]+0x721): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmps.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$read_bounds]+0x40): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmps.obj):(.text[glp_read_mps]+0x5ae): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmps.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_read_mps]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmps.obj):(.text[glp_write_mps]+0x1167): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmps.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_write_mps]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpcpx.obj):(.text[parse_constraints]+0x241): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpcpx.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$parse_constraints]+0x20): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpcpx.obj):(.text[glp_read_lp]+0x4e4): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpcpx.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_read_lp]+0x28): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpcpx.obj):(.text[glp_write_lp]+0xf87): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpcpx.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_write_lp]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi11.obj):(.text[glp_read_sol]+0x2ad): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi11.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_read_sol]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi11.obj):(.text[glp_print_ranges]+0xc4b): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi11.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_print_ranges]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi11.obj):(.text[glp_read_ipt]+0x1e0): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi11.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_read_ipt]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi11.obj):(.text[glp_read_mip]+0x1f9): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi11.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_read_mip]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi19.obj):(.text[glp_main]+0xe4b): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi19.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_main]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi07.obj):(.text[glp_exact]+0x24d): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi07.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_exact]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios09.obj):(.text[eval_degrad]+0x189): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios09.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$eval_degrad]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios07.obj):(.text[lpx_cover_cut]+0x51f): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios07.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$lpx_cover_cut]+0x24): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios06.obj):(.text[cmir_sep]+0xa1d): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios06.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$cmir_sep]+0x28): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios10.obj):(.text[_glp_ios_feas_pump]+0x125e): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpios10.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_ios_feas_pump]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl04.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_write_text]+0x111): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl04.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_write_text]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl04.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_error]+0x17): undefined reference to `__chkstk'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl04.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_error]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl04.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_warning]+0x17): undefined reference to `__chkstk'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl04.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_warning]+0x11a): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl04.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_warning]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpsdf.obj):(.text[glp_sdf_open_file]+0x118): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpsdf.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_sdf_open_file]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpgmp.obj):(.text[_glp_mpz_mul]+0x53b): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpgmp.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpz_mul]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpgmp.obj):(.text[_glp_mpz_cmp]+0x289): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpgmp.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpz_cmp]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpgmp.obj):(.text[_glp_mpz_add]+0x5ff): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpgmp.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpz_add]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpgmp.obj):(.text[_glp_mpz_div]+0x704): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpgmp.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpz_div]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi15.obj):(.text[glp_read_graph]+0x1b0): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi15.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_read_graph]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpdmx.obj):(.text[glp_read_mincost]+0x685): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpdmx.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_read_mincost]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpdmx.obj):(.text[glp_read_maxflow]+0x539): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpdmx.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_read_maxflow]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpdmx.obj):(.text[glp_read_asnprob]+0x4f3): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpdmx.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_read_asnprob]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpdmx.obj):(.text[glp_read_ccdata]+0x4fa): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpdmx.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_read_ccdata]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpdmx.obj):(.text[glp_read_prob]+0x1012): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpdmx.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_read_prob]+0x24): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi17.obj):(.text[glp_mincost_lp]+0x4b1): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi17.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_mincost_lp]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi17.obj):(.text[glp_maxflow_lp]+0x450): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi17.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_maxflow_lp]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi17.obj):(.text[glp_asnprob_lp]+0x35f): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpapi17.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$glp_asnprob_lp]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmat.obj):(.text[_glp_mat_amd_order1]+0x1a2): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmat.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mat_amd_order1]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmat.obj):(.text[_glp_mat_symamd_ord]+0x1a2): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmat.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mat_symamd_ord]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_format_symbol]+0x20d): undefined reference to `__security_check_cooki
e'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_format_symbol]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChec
k'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_concat_symbols]+0x211): undefined reference to `__security_check_cook
ie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_concat_symbols]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCh
eck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_format_tuple]+0x1f4): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie
'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_format_tuple]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChec
k'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_check_elem_set]+0x161): undefined reference to `__security_check_cook
ie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_check_elem_set]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCh
eck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_check_value_sym]+0x75b): undefined reference to `__security_check_coo
kie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_check_value_sym]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerC
heck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[display_set]+0x270): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$display_set]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[print_text]+0xb4): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$print_text]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_eval_numeric]+0xc4f): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie
'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_eval_numeric]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChec
k'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_eval_symbolic]+0x583): undefined reference to `__security_check_cooki
e'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_eval_symbolic]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChe
ck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[write_func]+0x192): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$write_func]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[printf_func]+0x1ca): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$printf_func]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_execute_table]+0xc75): undefined reference to `__security_check_cooki
e'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_execute_table]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChe
ck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_execute_printf]+0x240): undefined reference to `__security_check_cook
ie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl03.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_execute_printf]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChe
ck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_expression_10]+0x3d7): undefined reference to `__security_check_cooki
e'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_expression_10]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChec
k'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_expression_11]+0x22b): undefined reference to `__security_check_cooki
e'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_expression_11]+0x243): undefined reference to `__security_check_cooki
e'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_expression_11]+0x8): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChec
k'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_expression_12]+0x370): undefined reference to `__security_check_cooki
e'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_expression_12]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChec
k'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_expression_13]+0x370): undefined reference to `__security_check_cooki
e'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_expression_13]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChec
k'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_function_reference]+0x65e): undefined reference to `__security_check_
cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_function_reference]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandle
rCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_expression_list]+0x536): undefined reference to `__security_check_coo
kie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_expression_list]+0x20): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerC
heck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_iterated_expression]+0x3f3): undefined reference to `__security_check
_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_iterated_expression]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHand
lerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_expression_1]+0x239): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie
'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_expression_1]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck
'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_set_statement]+0x8da): undefined reference to `__security_check_cooki
e'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_set_statement]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerChec
k'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_parameter_statement]+0xb70): undefined reference to `__security_check
_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_parameter_statement]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__GSHand
lerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_variable_statement]+0x640): undefined reference to `__security_check_
cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_variable_statement]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandle
rCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_constraint_statement]+0x6b3): undefined reference to `__security_chec
k_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_constraint_statement]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHan
dlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_table_statement]+0xaa4): undefined reference to `__security_check_coo
kie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl01.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_table_statement]+0xc): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCh
eck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/colamd/colamd.obj):(.text[_glp_colamd]+0x3d6): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/colamd/colamd.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_colamd]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/colamd/colamd.obj):(.text[_glp_symamd]+0x596): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/colamd/colamd.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_symamd]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl06.obj):(.text[read_header]+0x2e8): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl06.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$read_header]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl06.obj):(.text[dbf_read_record]+0x1f4): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl06.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$dbf_read_record]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl06.obj):(.text[dbf_write_record]+0x315): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl06.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$dbf_write_record]+0x28): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl05.obj):(.text[_glp_mpl_fn_time2str]+0x92d): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'

libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpmpl05.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_mpl_fn_time2str]+0x20): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck
'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpsql.obj):(.text[_glp_db_iodbc_read]+0x1dc): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpsql.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_db_iodbc_read]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpsql.obj):(.text[extract_error]+0xf1): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpsql.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$extract_error]+0x14): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpsql.obj):(.text[db_iodbc_open_int]+0x92a): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpsql.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$db_iodbc_open_int]+0x10): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpsql.obj):(.text[_glp_db_iodbc_write]+0x387): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
libs/glpk.lib(../src/glpsql.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$_glp_db_iodbc_write]+0x18): undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MiMBL_GeneDel.exe] Error 1
```

Basically I started to give up on the precompiled libraries and want to compile boost with mingw-w64 mys self. The thought is I have many toolchains on my computer including GNU gcc and mingw(32bit). How can I specify boost to use 
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ to compile Boost?

Comment: vc100 is for Visual Studio 2010, not for mingw-w64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Boost Getting Started Guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) is a good starting point, but between running `bootstrap.sh` and invoking `b2` you'll need to edit your `user-config.jam` file to point it at your proper compiler as described in the [Boost.Build user manual](https://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/index.html) (under 'Common tasks -> Cross-compilation').

When you do invoke `b2`, you'll want to pass some extra arguments to make it build 64-bit binaries and let it know you're building with MinGW rather than mainline GCC:

```
target-os=windows architecture=x86 address-model=64
```

Comment: I added "using gcc : mingw64 : x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ ;". However with "toolset=gcc-mingw64" it now complains that "version 'mingw64' requested but 'g++-mingw64' not found and version '4.3.4' of default 'g++' does not match"

Comment: @SergejAndrejev : Try `using gcc : : x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ ;` in user-config.jam and `toolset=gcc` when invoking bjam (and make sure your user-config.jam file is in the root boost directory).

Comment: Yeah. That kind of did the trick. Though have other problem to solve in mean while. One was quite stupid of me (because of missing knowledge). When compiling boost with mingw32-w64 you will get tons of errors. Don't stop the compilation immediately, cos there are others libraries some parts of boost depend on. If you are not interested in these parts than you should be OK. I was interested in boost_filesystem and it was stand-alone library so I got away with it.

Comment: @SergejAndrejev : Boost.Filesystem depends on Boost.System, FYI.

Comment: yes. I knew that. But neither it or boost.system doesn't depend on any 3rd part library. It was to my surprise that some of boost libraries do depend on thing outside boost.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @ildjarn , I had to use `using gcc " " x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe` (note the .exe suffix) in project-config.jam. And, of course, x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe was in PATH.